# Как оптимизировать обращение к свойству allowedDates в datepicker Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify

Помогите пожалуйста.
Необходимо сделать неактивными для выбора даты в datepicker Vuetify, кроме тех которые приходят по api vuex в формате Timestamp.

Пробовал сделать с помощью allowedDates в datepicker Vuetify но получилось уж очень тяжелым.

```
allowedDates: function(val, store) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.$store.getters["films/convertTimestamp"].length; i++) {
    if (val.slice(-2) == this.$store.getters["films/convertTimestamp"][i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```